# Using Go deterministicly generate RSA Private Key with custom io.Reader

Tags: go, rsa

For reasons probably best left unanswered I need to generate infinite RSA public/private keys. Note this is not being used for anything highly secure, so please don't tell me not to do this, yes I know its not ideal. By "infinite" I mean I need a unknown number of them think billions to trillions, and creating them before being used is not possible.

Since this would consume infinite space and take infinite time to generate I need to do it at runtime.

However I also need to have for a given input the same key pair. This means I need to deterministically recreate the RSA key given the input.

I am using Go and normally you create keys using the following,

```
k, err := rsa.GenerateKey(rand.Reader, 2048)
```

Of course the catch is that `rand.Reader` is supplied by `crypto/rand` and as such there is no way to seed this.

I thought that it would be possible to provide my own reader implementation to achieve my goal. I looked through the source of `GenerateKey` and noted that it is looking for prime numbers, so I implemented my own reader, such that I could control the "random" primes returned, allowing me to generate the same key when required,

```
type Reader struct {
    data   []byte
    sum    int
    primes []int
}

func NewReader(toRead string) *Reader {
    primes := sieveOfEratosthenes(10_000_000)
    return &Reader{[]byte(toRead), 0, primes}
}

func (r *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    r.sum = r.sum + 1

    if r.sum >= 100_000 {
        return r.primes[rand.Intn(len(r.primes))], io.EOF
    }

    return r.primes[rand.Intn(len(r.primes))], nil
}

func sieveOfEratosthenes(N int) (primes []int) {
    b := make([]bool, N)
    for i := 2; i < N; i++ {
        if b[i] == true {
            continue
        }
        primes = append(primes, i)
        for k := i * i; k < N; k += i {
            b[k] = true
        }
    }
    return
}
```

I can then call into generate key like so

```
k, err := rsa.GenerateKey(NewReader(""), 2048)
```

Which compiles, but crashes at runtime due to nil pointers. I am fairly comfortable with Go, but the implementation of RSA for this is beyond my understanding. Looking for either a better way to achieve this, or perhaps what I need to do to get my reader working.

Note, the only hard requirement's I have here are being able to generate the same key for a given input, and use `rsa.GenerateKey` or a drop in compatible replacement. The input can be anything really, so long as I get the same key as the output.

Here is a Go playground link demonstrating where I am currently https://go.dev/play/p/jd1nAoPR5aD

Comment: The size of these numbers is the most important variable affecting their generation time. What size moduli do you need? Any other requirements on the public and private exponents?

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Ideally id like the generation time to cut down. I could of course calculate the primes once and reuse the output for what I have above which is just an example. The only hard requirement I have is that I need to deterministically create the key when supplied an input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Read` method is not doing what is expected. It does not fill the input `p` byte slice with random bytes. If you look at the [implementation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/crypto/rand/rand_unix.go) for Unix of `crypto/rand.Read` method, it passes the input byte slice into another reader. So basically you what you need to fill the byte slice with random numbers. For example:

```
func (r *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
        i := 0
        b := p

        for i < len(b) {
                if len(b) < 4 {
                        b[0] = 7
                        b = b[1:]
                } else {
                        binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(rand.Intn(len(r.primes))))
                        b = b[4:]
                }
        }

        return len(p), nil
}
```

Here is the [link](https://go.dev/play/p/6RBx1J-79eY) to playground.

---

UPD

As mentioned in the answer by Erwin, there is a function called `MaybeReadRand` that with 50% chance read 1 byte from rand reader to make this function nondeterministic. But you can get around by adding if statement in Read method: if length of the input slice is 1, then ignore everything and return. Otherwise, feed the input slice with prime numbers:

```
func (r *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    i := 0
    b := p

    if len(p) == 1 {
        println("maybeReadRand")
        return 1, nil
    }

    for i < len(b) {
        if len(b) < 4 {
            b[0] = 7
            b = b[1:]
        } else {
            binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(r.primes[r.i]))
            r.i++
            b = b[4:]
        }
    }

    return len(p), nil
}
```

In this [snippet](https://go.dev/play/p/1B1KhY_5AHi) I am creating 2 keys, and both of them are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to fork RSA but this has resolved it for me totally. I wish I could award some monetary reward here somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted an answer here, and I was about to award it to them as it got me the final piece I needed to resolve the question.

In short, I didn't read how the read was being called properly and I needed to populate the input slice. Changing the read to the below,

```
func (r *Reader) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    i := 0
    b := p

    for i < len(b) {
        if len(b) < 4 {
            b[0] = 7
            b = b[1:]
        } else {
            binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(b, uint32(rand.Intn(len(r.primes))))
            b = b[4:]
        }
    }

    return len(p), nil
}
```

resolves the crashes, and since it is now using `math/rand` I can set the seed for the list of primes allowing me to ensure it is deterministic. Everything solved without needing anything from 3rd parties. Excellent.

To whoever posted that, if you post again I will award you the accepted answer.

Comment: Hey, that was me. I thought my answer does not fully resolve your problem because you want **deterministic** implementation, and my proposal only make "Read" function work.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a strange assumption. `rand.Reader` returns completely random data. It doesn't return prime numbers. `rsa.GenerateKey` uses the data internally to come up with -very probable- prime numbers. But it doesn't depend on any particular pattern in the reader. In fact, it prefers there to be no pattern (and "being a prime number" is definitely a pattern)

Sure, you're free to feed `rsa.GenerateKey`m, or excerpts from Shakespeare's works, but `rsa.GenerateKey` is not going to make use of the fact that it is.

So running a sieve of Eratosthenes is a waste of time (literally).

If `rsa.GenerateKey` allowed you to deterministically generate keys, then you could directly generate bytes using a pseudo-random number generator that uses a seed, directly.

But, that's not the case. Look at [the source code, line 287 of rsa.go](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a5a47442502e8e42b390f458f8f91dea3de872eb/src/crypto/rsa/rsa.go#L287):

```
func GenerateMultiPrimeKey(random io.Reader, nprimes int, bits int) (*PrivateKey, error) {
    randutil.MaybeReadByte(random) // <------- this line here is the important one
```

The function `GenerateMultiPrimeKey` is directly invoked by `GenerateKey`.

Now what does [`randutil.MaybeReadByte`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a5a47442502e8e42b390f458f8f91dea3de872eb/src/crypto/internal/randutil/randutil.go#L25) do? The documentation is clear:

> MaybeReadByte reads a single byte from r with ~50% probability. This
> is used to ensure that callers do not depend on non-guaranteed
> behaviour, e.g. assuming that rsa.GenerateKey is deterministic w.r.t.
> a given random stream.

In short, it ensures that **it is not possible to deterministically generate a particular RSA key**.

If you still needed to do that, you would need to copy the source code of `GenerateMultiPrimeKey` to your own library, and remove the line `randutil.MaybeReadByte`. Or you'd need to rethink what your requirement really is, a level higher than you're currently thinking, and see if there is a different way to achieve your requirement. (Have a look at the ["XY problem"](https://xyproblem.info/))

Comment: Ah yes you are 100% right. randutil.MaybeReadByte is going to be an issue here. As mentioned I only skimmed the code, and clearly needed more coffee before looking at the prime number part. That said I have the sieve for computing backup amounts so it was free code for my test. I think I might need to fork the code in my case to remove that maybe portion.

Comment: I think it's not a big issue as "MaybeReadByte" always read only 1 byte. https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.19.4:src/crypto/internal/randutil/randutil.go;l=35;drc=a5a47442502e8e42b390f458f8f91dea3de872eb

Comment: So my point is that, the reader always can know if the caller MaybeReadByte by checking the length of the input slice. If it's 1 byte length, then fill it with any value as the caller MaybeReadByte.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a deterministic-random `io.Reader`, here's how to do it with the standard library

```golang
import (
    "io"
    "math/rand"
)

func main() {
    const seed = 1
    var myRand = rand.New(rand.NewSource(seed))
}
```

`rand.NewSource` creates a deterministic seeded random source, and `rand.New` wraps it to create a more featureful `*Rand` object, which includes an implementation of `io.Reader`.

You can also reset the `*Rand` by calling `myRand.Seed(seed)`.